# MongoDB 'near' geospatial query of array of GeoJSON polygons

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

What I would like to do is a have a query which finds documents which have **a** volume (any point in the volume) which is within some distance. I sadly cannot modify the document structure which I am using without a pretty major overhaul. I can implement this on the application side, but that would require a large data transfer.

I have a document which contains data in this format:

```
{  
   "volumes":[  
      {  
         "volume":{  
            "type":"Polygon",
            "coordinates":[  
               [  

               ]
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Example query which will not work:

```
{  
   'volumes.volume':{  
      '$geoWithin':{  
         '$centerSphere':[  
            [  
               0,
               0
            ],
            3.14159
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

This sort of does what I want, but does 'within' instead of 'intersects', also I don't believe that it would work with **any** volume, but only if all volumes (correct me if I'm wrong) are within.

I may let my ignorance show a bit here but in general the optimum query would do something like (although I'm aware this wouldn't work):

```
{  
   'volumes':{  
      '$elemMatch':{  
         'volume':{  
            '$near':{  
               '$geometry':reference_point,
               '$maxDistance':distance
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Clarity check:  You say "...find a volume within a distance."   So, if I say the center point is X,Y and distance is R, find all polygons that are completely circumscribed?

Comment: It would be like checking if a circle of radius R at point X,Y and the volume/polygon intersects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Neel Rathod, I used a geoNear query specifying a maxDistance and a GeoJSON point.

First create an index on your collection specifying a 2dsphere, this tells geoNear where to look for coordinates (even works on an array of Polygons!):

```
db.[collection].createIndex({'volumes.volume', '2dsphere'})
```

The aggregate call now returns the documents which satisfy the maxDistance condition from the geoJSON point.

```
db.[collection].aggregate({
    '$geoNear': {
        # geoJSON point for result in meters, legacy for result in radians
        'near': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [0,0]}, 
        'distanceField': 'distance', # field to store distance
        'spherical': 'true', # ensures proper calculation and d in meters
        'maxDistance': 1000 # meters
    }
})
```

Bonus points: 
Including a `'includeLocs': 'true'` will allow you to differentiate the volume which the geoNear operation determined was near.

Answer (score 1):

I think you already have two coordinates and distance, First you need to use `$geoNear` to find nearest location from given coordinates for example :

```
db.places.aggregate([
{
 $geoNear: {
    near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.99279 , 40.719296 ] },
    distanceField: "dist.calculated",
    query: { type: "public" },
    includeLocs: "dist.location",
    num: 1,
    spherical: true
 }
}
])
```

It gives you the nearst location from given location. after that you need use a npm module `geoLib` https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib
in that module use `geolib.isPointInCircle` function which takes 3 paramters first 2 is lat & lng and third is radius (distance) and gives you boolean value. if location1 and location2 are in distance it's return true otherwise false.

```
const geolib = require('geolib');

db.places.aggregate([{
    $geoNear: {
        near: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [-73.99279, 40.719296]
        },
        distanceField: "dist.calculated",
        query: {
            type: "public"
        },
        includeLocs: "dist.location",
        num: 1,
        spherical: true
    } 
}]).then((result) => {
    if (result) {
        const isMatch = geolib.isPointInCircle({
                latitude: 51.525,
                longitude: 7.4575
            }, {
                latitude: 51.5175,
                longitude: 7.4678
            },
           5000 //Your distance in meters
        );
        if (isMatch === true) {
            console.log('You are near to me');
        } else {
            console.log('You are far from me');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any reason you avoided the use of the maxDistance field in the geoNear query?

Comment: Yes because I have already a radius (distance)  which stored in another table, So in my case first I find the nearest place and compare it's fall in given lat,  lng as well as radius with geolib,  it's up to your requirements.